# Formatted NSLog string stopped working correctly since Xcode 15

Tags: xcode, printf, nslog

I've used this macro successfully up until upgrading to Xcode 15:

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...)   NSLog((fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

for outputting debug logging, for example:

```
LOG(@"%.2f", fAngle)
```

But since upgrading to Xcode 15 the NSlog command no longer takes into account the number of decimal places I'm specifying, and displays all decimal places as if I've written just "%f".

Am I doing something wrong?